# How to apply a Bootstrap combobox to a Flask combobox?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I would like to use a Bootstrap combobox with the Flask combobox. Currently the Flask combobox works fine for me. How can I apply the Bootstrap button graphic to it?

**Bootstrap Combobox**

```
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Small button
  </button>
```

**Flask Code**

```
<form name="Item_1" action="/combobox" method="POST">
    <select name="colours">
      {% for colour in colours %}
        {% if colour == chosen %}
         <option value="{{ colour }}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>
        {% else %}
         <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
        {% endif %}     
      {% endfor %}     
   </select>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your Flask code in the following method to give your Flask combobox the Bootstrap button styling:

```html
<form name="Item_1" action="/combobox" method="POST">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Select Color
    </button>
    <select class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" name="colours">
      {% for colour in colours %}
        {% if colour == chosen %}
          <option value="{{ colour }}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>
        {% else %}
          <option value="{{ colour }}">{{ colour }}</option>
        {% endif %}     
      {% endfor %}     
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This code covers the button and select components in a btn-group div. The select element has the class btn btn-secondary btn-sm, which gives it the Bootstrap styling, and the button has the classes btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle, which makes it resemble the Bootstrap button.

Last but not least, to give it the Bootstrap primary button style, the input element for the submit button has the class btn btn-primary btn-sm.